# Getting null at media player setDataSource

Tags: android, video, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set video as background in my app, however got problem -  I'm still getting null at line mp.setDataSource(video) in my activity. I've tried to find solution but found nothing similar. Any advice what I'm doing wrong ?

I put my video file in res/raw folder. 
`

```
public class EnterActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback` 

    private MediaPlayer mp = null;
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.video_surface);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video);

        mp.setDataSource(video);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get the dimensions of the video
        int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

        //Get the width of the screen
        int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
        lp.width = screenWidth;

        //Set the height of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video
        //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
        lp.height = (int) (((float)videoHeight / (float)videoWidth) * (float)screenWidth);

        //Commit the layout parameters
        mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        //Start video
        mp.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: I don't have exception right now, it looks like video is not loading - all I can see is white screen :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this results in a correct URI:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.video)
```

You can create a MediaPlayer for a given raw resource like this:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
```

Comment: Thanks for response ... unfortunately right now I'm getting only white screen :/

Comment: What should I put in method mp.setDataSource() if I create mp like you suggest ?

Comment: You should not need to set a datasource then. Just do all the other stop, e.g. Prepare and start the video.

Comment: It's still not working. java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
            at pl.krakowskascenamuzyczna.ksmcalendar.Activities.EnterActivity.surfaceCreated(EnterActivity.java:47)      line 47 is mp.prepare();